# How to get Vertices from a Community in R?

Tags: r

I've extracted communities from a graph using the walk.trap function from R.

```
com <- walktrap.community(g2)
```

Now, I want to get the vertices from each communities in order to compare communities from different time frames

If I wrote `com[1]`, for example, I got a list of the first community members, but I can't get the individuals from the list

```
com[1]
$`1`
 [1] "Siqiang Luo"                 "Yifeng Luo"                 
 [3] "Shuigeng Zhou"               "Gao Cong"                   
 [5] "Shanshan Feng"               "Xuefeng Chen"               
 [7] "Yifeng Zeng"                 "Yeow Meng Chee"             
 [9] "Muthukumaran Chandrasekaran" "Prashant Doshi"             
[11] "Kenneth Bogert"              " Yifeng Luo"                
[13] " Gao Cong"                   " Jihong Guan"               
[15] " Xuefeng Chen"               " Yifeng Zeng"               
[17] " Yeow Meng Chee"             " Yanping Xiang"             
[19] " Prashant Doshi"             " Yingke Chen"
```

Any help, please?

Comment: e.g. `com[[1]][1]` ? If you want more specific help, you will need to specify your package and provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Also try `str(com)`. It will show you how the object is structured. Perhaps there are methods for calling data out of this object? What class is `com`?